# ANTLR Lua long string grammar rules

Tags: parsing, lua, antlr, lexer, antlr3

I'm trying to create ANTLR parser for Lua. So i took grammar produced by Nicolai Mainero(available at ANTLR's site, Lua 5.1 grammar) and begin to work.

Grammar is good. One thing not working: LONG STRINGS.

Lua specification rule: Literal

> strings can also be defined using a
>   long format enclosed by long brackets.
>   We define an opening long bracket of
>   level n as an opening square bracket
>   followed by n equal signs followed by
>   another opening square bracket. So, an
>   opening long bracket of level 0 is
>   written as [[, an opening long bracket
>   of level 1 is written as [=[, and so
>   on. A closing long bracket is defined
>   similarly; for instance, a closing
>   long bracket of level 4 is written as
>   ]====]. A long string starts with an
>   opening long bracket of any level and
>   ends at the first closing long bracket
>   of the same level. Literals in this
>   bracketed form can run for several
>   lines, do not interpret any escape
>   sequences, and ignore long brackets of
>   any other level. They can contain
>   anything except a closing bracket of
>   the proper level.the proper level.

My question is close by meaning to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023722/matching-luas-long-bracket-string-syntax) but tools are different.

Some little example of LONGSTRING:

```
local a = [==[ Some interesting string [=[ sub string in string ]=] [hello indexes] [[And some line strings]] ]==] - its correct string. 
local f = [==[ Not interesting string ]=] - incorrect string
```

Here my rule for LONGSTRING with out '=' symbol:

```
LONGSTRING: '[[' (~(']') | ']'(~(']')))* ']]';
```

Can somebody help me? Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget about long comments. They are just like long strings, but begin with `--[[` and end with `]]`. Naturally they also allow 0 or more `=` signs so that they can be unambiguously nested.

Comment: @RBerteig, good point. I didn't mention them specifically in my answer, but they are handled properly in the snippet of the grammar I posted.

Comment: @Bart, true, as long as your rule for a comment handles `"--"` followed by `LONGSTRING` without whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once wrote a Lua grammar according the specs and solved it like this:

```
grammar Lua;

// ... options ...

// ... tokens ...

@lexer::members {
    public boolean noCloseAhead(int numEqSigns) {
        if(input.LA(1) != ']') return true;
        for(int i = 2; i < numEqSigns+2; i++) {
            if(input.LA(i) != '=') return true;
        }
        return input.LA(numEqSigns+2) != ']';
    }

    public void matchClose(int numEqSigns) throws MismatchedTokenException {
        StringBuilder eqSigns = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < numEqSigns; i++) {
            eqSigns.append('=');
        }
        match("]"+eqSigns+"]");
    }
}

// ... parser rules ...

String
  :  '"'  (~('"'  | '\\') | EscapeSequence)* '"'
  |  '\'' (~('\'' | '\\') | EscapeSequence)* '\''
  |  LongBracket
  ;

Comment
  :  (BlockComment | LineComment) {skip();}
  ;

fragment
BlockComment
  :  '--' LongBracket 
  ;

fragment
LineComment
  :  '--' ~('\r' | '\n')* ('\r'? '\n' | EOF) 
  ;

fragment
LongBracket
@init {int openEq = 0;}
  :  '[' ('=' {openEq++;})* '[' ({noCloseAhead(openEq)}?=> .)* {matchClose(openEq);}
  ;

// ... more lexer rules ...
```

Be careful with what you find on the ANTLR Wiki! As the name suggests: it's a Wiki and one can post stuff fairly easy. The Lua grammar you mention is a nice start, but has quite a bit of errors in it (binary or hex literals are incorrect as well, at least, at the time I looked at it...).