# ANTLR generated Cpp file throws errors on Lua comments

Tags: c++, antlr

```
In member function ‘bool LuaLexerCyclicDFA6::msynpred(PredType)’:
     error: ‘LuaLexerCyclicDFA6::CtxType’ has no member named ‘msynpred’
```

Building with -language Cpp and here is the part that is throwing the error :

```
BLOCK_COMMENT
    :   '--[[' ( options {greedy=false;} : . )* '--]]' 
    ;

LINE_COMMENT 
    : '--' ~('\n'|'\r')* '\r' ? '\n'
    ;
```

Wondering if anyone has an idea how this error is being caused.

Compiling with g++ 4.6

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the rules you posted. Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that produces this error? Also, Lua block comments don't have to end with `'--]]'`, and they can also look like this: `--[=[ ... ]] ... ]=]` (which is a single block comment)

Comment: Oh thanks for the note about that comment. I didnt know that. Anyway, I fixed the issue by implementing some left factoring.

Comment: You're welcome @Ross. Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065327/antlr-lua-long-string-grammar-rules